# How to remove transfer or cancel message from event confirmation emails.

Tags: civievent, confirmation

We are using Civi 4.7.22 on Wordpress 4.8.22

I just realized that the below message goes out in all event confirmation emails whether or not the box in the event configurations is checked.   I would really like to remove this message.  Can someone tell me where to do that?

***You may transfer your registration to another participant or cancel your registration up to 96 hours before the event. Cancellations are not refundable.
Click here to transfer or cancel your registration.***

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
Message templates > System Workflow Messages > Events (receipt only).
Modify the lines on the bottom of HTML Format.

Comment: Are you saying the the message is included even if a setting is not set on the Event to say this should be allowed? if so, sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: The 'transfer event registration' dialog has you type the contact's first, last, email (all required, with no lookup, which is funny) and then offers no checkbox about sending an email about the transfer notice. this is on civicrm 5.x